# Remove DONE tasks from agenda view

Tags: org-mode

This seems like a common use, so I suspect I'm missing something...

During my daily planning, I add or remove tasks for the day by changing the task's scheduled day (C-c s). I use column view while in the agenda view for the day to see how much I've scheduled for the day. When I complete a task, I mark it DONE.

I don't want the DONE tasks to show up in this view because their time still contributes to the total (I want a running total of what I have left in the day).

But I can't figure-out how to filter by TODO status. '/' lets me filter by tag, but how do I filter by status?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what you want is to set `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` to `t`.

See the Manual: [Deadlines and Scheduling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html#index-org_002dagenda_002dskip_002dscheduled_002dif_002ddone-817).  It will hide any scheduled tasks that are already completed.

Comment: Similarly, there is an `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done` variable for deadlines, which is what I was looking for and this answer helped me find.

Comment: Just in case someone like me prefers to keep the timestamp on the same line as the todo entry, there's another variable besides the above two: `org-agenda-skip-timestamp-if-done` that you may wanna try too. Those items on my list marked DONE only disappear after I set it to `t` as well.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me, so I came up with my own. Adding this line to your init file implements the desired behavior:

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-function-global '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
```

Here is the source which led me to the answer https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Agenda-Views.html.

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumbled on this and found toggling `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` not work, use `C-c C-x C-a` to add `:ARCHIVE:` tag. Org will skip tasks tagged *ARCHIVE*.

http://orgmode.org/manual/Archiving.html#Archiving